# ERC-4337 - Bundler development

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, erc-4337, account-abstraction

I understood the ERC-4337, but I need to develop a Bundler for my job. But I don't know how to do it, I researched about it but I didn't find any great content. Please give me tips and explain how can I do it, please

Answer (score 0):

There are number of bundler's code available on the github . In all of them i think `eth-infinitism` bundler is good as it is written in javascript . Here is the [link](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/bundler) .